# When will an ellipse ‘fall’ into a parabola?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems, tangent-line

[image]

Consider the parabola $y=x^2$ and an ellipse which ‘rests’ on it, given by the equation $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} +\frac{(y-h)^2}{b^2}=1$$The goal is to find all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ for which the ellipse doesn’t fall to the origin, namely it touches the parabola at two distinct points.

Replacing $y$ by $x^2$ in the equation of the ellipse, we get $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} +\frac{(x^2-h)^2}{b^2}=1 $$

I could calculate the discriminant of this quadratic in $x^2$ and set it $\gt 0$. Is there a quick and neat way to express $h$ in terms of $a,b$? Or maybe another approach to solve this problem?

Comment: I would just substitute a variable for $x^2$ then use quadratic formula.

Comment: @Ty. That would give the points where the two meet. What now?

Comment: If the discriminant is degenerate, aka $0$, then there is only one solution. Otherwise, there are two. This actually works in a more profound level, as it is linked with Bézout's theorem in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd look at the problem in a different way.  Suppose we are given $b = h > 0$ such that the ellipse touches the parabola's vertex.  What is the largest $a$, say $a^*$, such that the ellipse has no other intersection points with the parabola?  For $a > a^*$, the ellipse cannot have $h = b$, thus such an $(a,b)$ pair cannot "fall" all the way down to the vertex.

As such, we require $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-b)^2}{b^2} = 1, \\ y = x^2,$$ hence $$a^2 y^2 + (b^2 - 2a^2 b) y = 0,$$ for which the unique nonzero root in $y$ is $$y = \frac{(2a^2 - b)b}{a}.$$  Therefore, if this root exists and is positive, the ellipse has another intersection point with the parabola other than its vertex; i.e., if $2a^2 > b$ or $$a > a^* = \sqrt{b/2}.$$  It follows that the set of all ordered pairs for which the ellipse cannot touch the vertex are those pairs for which $a > \sqrt{b/2}$.

---

By request, there is the question of how to express $h$ as a function of $(a,b)$ for ellipses satisfying the condition $a > \sqrt{b/2}$.  This involves only a slight modification of the above calculation, namely we solve the system $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-h)^2}{b^2} = 1, \\ y = x^2$$ for $y$, giving $$y = h - \frac{b^2}{2a^2} \pm \frac{b \sqrt{4a^4 + b^2 - 4a^2 h}}{2a^2}.$$  Then we note that under the assumptions $a > \sqrt{b/2}$ and $h \ge b$, we have $h - b^2/(2a^2) > h - b > 0$.  When the ellipse is tangent to the parabola, the solution has a unique double root; i.e., the the discriminant $4a^2 + b^2 - 4a^2 h$ must be zero, or $$h = a^2 + \frac{b^2}{4a^2}.$$  This characterizes the location of such an ellipse when $h \ge b$.

Comment: What if $h\ne b$?

Comment: @Tavish if $h \ne b$, the ellipse cannot possibly be tangent to the vertex of the parabola.

Comment: @Tavish Perhaps my original answer is not sufficiently clear.  The idea here is to consider all the cases in which the ellipse is tangent to the parabola at its vertex--that is, it "falls down" all the way to the bottom.  Then by construction, we must have $h = b$.  Now "fatten" the ellipse as much as possible before it can no longer fit in the parabola.  That is the maximum $a$ allowed for that choice of $b$.  If $a$ is any larger, the ellipse will be "lifted" off the vertex, i.e. $h > b$.

Comment: Fantastic. Additionally, for $h\gt b$ could you also suggest a way of writing $h$ in terms of $a,b$?

Comment: $a=\sqrt{b/2}$ corresponds to ellipse and parabola having the same curvature at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Aretino Comparing local curvature is not enough, even for convex bodies.  For example, the superellipse $$x^6 + y^6 = 1$$ has a smaller radius of curvature compared to the parabola $$(x-y)^2 + (x+y-2^{5/6}) = 0$$ at the point of tangency $x = y = 2^{-1/6}$, but also intersects the parabola at approximately $$(x,y) = (0.32049051, 0.99981930)$$ and $$(x,y) = (-0.997066296, 0.5094057389)$$ as well as their reflections across $y = x$.

Comment: Yes, of course: I wasn't suggesting that as a general rule. But that works when both curves are symmetric about an axis passing through the tangency point, as in the case at hand.

Comment: @Aretino Can you explain in more detail your assertion regarding an axis of symmetry through the tangency point?